# What methods exist to prove a best strategy?

Tags: game-theory, card-games, decision-theory

In decision or game theory, what methods exist to prove a "best" strategy? For example: Consider a game where a standard deck is shuffled and one card drawn face-down. The single player wins if they can identify the card. I claim there is no better strategy than random guessing. How can this be proven?

Comment: Well, that one seems tautological.  That is..."shuffled" means that each slot has an equal probability of being occupied by each card, therefore each guess has a $\frac 1{52}$ probability of being correct regardless of the origin of the guess.

Comment: @lulu: 
 
Note that the game with a pure random-guessing strategy is only one example, not the core of the question. Consider a second example: Keep the same shuffle and change the game to two card-draws (dealt and viewed one after the other). Now the optimal strategy is not just random guessing (i.e., on the second card, one should avoid picking the first card viewed). What techniques would prove that we have the optimal strategy for this modified game?

Comment: Well, as an entirely general matter, it is quite hard to obtain an optimal strategy in a game and even harder to prove that you have done so.  After all, for games with complex rules it is hard to describe the space of possible strategies (and much harder if you are dealing with opponents who have unknown strategies of their own). I think your question is too general to admit a useful response.

Comment: I suggest adding the big-list tag and I'd also recommend listing the ones you already know, which I assume at least includes brute force.

Comment: @lulu: If there is any work, citation, reference, or name to this difficult general problem I'd love to know and be able to read up on them.